# Convert and sort varchar Date dd-MMM-yyyy

Tags: sql-server, date, sql-server-2012

I'm using a table that has the date as varchar. example dateformat:
17-Jun-2015 
I have tried the following ways to convert and sort the date(dd-MMM-yyyy) to dateTime.

```
SELECT date, name, author
FROM sometable
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, date, 106) DESC
```

I have also tried converting the date in the select statement. doesn't work. The error is

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

The conversion types through some similar questions but I have not found any solutions to the format I have. Is there some way of selecting the delimiter between the day month and year??

I also had a browse through this link which has the formats for `datetime` formats. 106 was the closest to my `varchar` date. Only my date in the table has '-' between day month and year.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

It should be absolutely fine to use 106 to convert your date format.

But I guess your table contains some of the invalid values in the column causes the error, try to spot them out by [TRY_CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx):

```
SELECT date, name, author, TRY_CONVERT(datetime, date, 106) AS convertresult
FROM sometable
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(datetime, date, 106) IS NULL AND date IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use date style `113` to convert to datetime format like this:

```
DECLARE @date VARCHAR(20) = '17-Jun-2015';

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CAST(@date AS DATETIME),113)
```